# Facebook fbAsyncInit firing twice

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's Javascript SDK to allow login/logout, and my problem is that when I use their window.fbAsyncInit call to initiate the FB session, it always fires twice.  I've included a simplified code sample. I'd appreciate any help!

In the code below, the "2" alert fires a single time, and then the "1" alert fires twice.

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
...some of my own functions, not related to Facebook...
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId   : '<?php echo FACEBOOK_APPID; ?>',
      session : <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>, status:false, cookie:true,  xfbml: true 
    });

    alert("1");

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.session) { ...do stuff... } else { ...do other stuff...}
    });

};

alert("2");

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e); 
}());

</script>
...page contents...
</body></html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not including two different Facebook javascripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might accidentally be including two different Facebook javascripts.

Comment: INdeed, thsi was the problem.  I caught it a while ago, but thanks!